# Receiving data from server using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am new to reactjs, I am receiving the data from server but not able to update the state. I receiving the error from .then(response => {this.setState({ reponse }).i am getting input from server as json data.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      posts:"hello"
    };
  }
componentWillMount() {
    axios.get(`http://192.168.1.9:8082`)
      .then(response => {this.setState({ posts});

      });
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.state.posts}</h1>


      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default App;
```

Comment: What is the error? Share that also

Comment: I bet it's because there is no `post` defined. Maybe you should make something like `this.setState({ posts: response.data })`?

Comment: Are you sure there is a posts property on the response and not response.data.posts as has been suggested?

Answer (score 1):

You have several typos.

1 .

```
.then(response => {this.setState({ post })
```

Where is your `post`? Should be something like `response.post` I guess

2 .

```
this.state = {
  posts:"hello"
};
...
this.setState({ post })
```

`post`, or `posts`?

3 .

```
<h1> {this.response}</h1>
```

What is `this.response`? You never declare it.

Fix these typos, it should work.

Comment: oh ouch sorry its  this.setState({posts})

Comment: i am receiving the data from server but i am not able to display it. I think i have done wrong in this part ".then(response => {this.setState({ posts});"

Comment: Just like I said (the first one), posts doesn't exist at all. should be something like `response.data.posts` or `response.posts`

Comment: It depends on what is the server response.